# Cypress - Iterate over each element and perform some action before moving to next iteration / element

Tags: cypress

I have below issue in cypress:

1. Get all table cells of a particular column containing a button.
2. Iterate over each cell --> locate button within that cell.
3. click on that button.
4. wait for modal dialog to appear
5. accept on modal and wait for it to disappear.
6. wait for a notification to appear and then disappear.
7. move to next cell element / iteration

Code that I have so far:

```js
  cy.get("tr[some attribute]").each(($element, $index, $list) => {
    cy.wrap($element).find("button").click();
    cy.get(".modal-dialog").should('be.visible');
    cy.get(".modal-dialog button[type='submit']").should('be.visible').click();
    cy.get("toast").should('be.visible').as('@toast')
    cy.get('@toast').should('not.be.visible')
  })
```

Issues Here:

1. The cypress doesn't waits for the first iteration to finish and runs all iteration. I can see multiple modal-dialogs opened up.
2. Cypress asynchronously clicks on all the buttons without waiting for previous iteration to finish.
3. cypress fails on step where it expects toast to disappear although i can see the toast message is not there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran a simple app with modal and toast. If you fix the toast part of the test it's possible to iterate the rows with `.each()`

To fix the toast you need to drop the alias and `cy.get('toast')` a 2nd time.

The alias value is stored internally and will not change when `should()` executes a retry. Remember, toast will stay on screen for some seconds so you must use retry to  test it has gone. (You may need to increase timeout depending on toast duration).

Minimal changes to fix:

```js
cy.get("tr[some attribute]").each(($row) => {
  cy.wrap($row).find("button").click();
  
  cy.get(".modal-dialog").should('be.visible');
  cy.get(".modal-dialog button[type='submit']").should('be.visible').click();

  cy.get("toast").should('be.visible')
  // timeout must exceed toast auto-close period
  // if you run the test in background or in CI, allow a few seconds extra
  cy.get('toast', {timeout:10000}).should('not.be.visible') 

})
```

I only get one toast on the screen at a time and the iteration waits for  `cy.get('toast', {timeout:10000}).should('not.be.visible')`  to complete.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but just for my knowledge why wouldn't a loop using each work in the same way as a recursive logic?

Comment: why would 'each' loop run over without finishing its previous iteration tasks.

Comment: I can't say why for your code without trying it out, but I know that iterating over test code that involves some DOM changing action is prone to failure, and the solution is generally recursion. I can mock it up later and post findings - but you tell me, does the each loop work if you fix (or remove) the toast test?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works after removing the alias, but I wonder why the code with alias won't work because the alias points to previously located element which we want to wait till it disappears rather than locating the element again and asserting for it to disappear?

Comment: Actually, the alias does work on my test if I add a timeout to `cy.get('@toast')`. Probably depends on the toast component implementation. If you post a repo, I'll check further.

Answer (score 3):

1/2. By the looks of it, it seems you are fetching all the rows and then iterating through each row. If a button html element only exists in the column you stating than you move the `.find()` command just above the `.each()`.

3. The alias seems a bit unnecessary if you are only using it for a command immediately after the alias set. Also since v6.0.0, the assertion should be [`not.exist`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#6-0-0).

Here is what your update code should look like.

```
cy.get("tr[some attribute]")
  .each( $row => {
     cy.wrap($row)
       .find("button[type=submit") // get only cell with button type submit
       .should('be.visible') // may want to play around with command timeouts based on your button appearing
       .click()
     cy.get(".modal-dialog")
       .should('be.visible') // modal appears
       .find(button[type='submit']")
       .should('be.visible') // button appears in modal
       .click();
     cy.get("toast").should('be.visible') 
     cy.get("toast").should('not.be.visible')
})
```

Comment: Questionable use of not.exist - only use it if you know the element is removed (could be display none)

Comment: Thanks for your response, my requirement is to fetch all rows, then start iterating over them, then wait till buttons load / appear / become clickable, then perform next set of actions.

Comment: Does a button html element exist in multiple columns in the table?

Comment: well there are several buttons in a row but the one i am interested is of type='submit'

Comment: Okay, adding that to the `.find()` selector will only get the button with type submit. I updated the answer.