# Click multiple: true cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a page where I land that have about 15 icons on it all with the same source. The way im grabbing each element looks like this:

```
cy.get('[src="someSource"]').click({ multiple: true })
```

The issue that have is that after clicking on an icon I have a model that pops up where I need to click another button before I can continue to the next icon.

I there a way for me to add another click in between each of these icons ?

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70857553/16997707) for an example that might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `each()` for this:

```js
cy.get('[src="someSource"]').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).click()
  //code to click the modal button
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70857553/16997707) cut down as your requirements are different.

You'll need to check the modal selectors for differences.

```js
cy.get("selector").each(($el) => {

  $el.click();  // actually no need to wrap as click works in jQuery
  
  cy.get(".modal-dialog").should('be.visible');
  cy.get(".modal-dialog button[type='submit']").click();

  cy.get(".modal-dialog").should('not.be.visible');  // wait for modal to go before next click
})
```